# Why Ramdajs.filter() works in my code and Ramdajs.find() not?

Tags: ramda.js

I have a js object like

```
var storage = [
1:{"index":1, "label": abc, "value": 33},
2:{"index":2, "label": def, "value": 43},
etc.
];
```

so, now i need to extract a given inner object given a "label" value

i find working:

```
R.filter( R.propEq( "label", labelname ), storage )
```

but find() isn't working:

```
R.find( R.propEq( 'label', labelname ))( storage )
```

can anybody enlighten me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your data structure.  Doing it like this, both `filter` and `find` seems to work fine:

```
var abc = "ABC", def = "DEF";

var storage = [
  {"index":1, "label": abc, "value": 33},
  {"index":2, "label": def, "value": 43},
  {"index":1, "label": abc, "value": 53},
];

var labelname = abc;

R.filter( R.propEq( "label", labelname ), storage );
//=> [{"index":1,"label":"ABC","value":33},{"index":1,"label":"ABC","value":53}]
R.find( R.propEq( "label", labelname ), storage );
//=> {"index":1,"label":"ABC","value":33}
```

You can see this in action on **[the Ramda REPL](http://goo.gl/2XBYso)**.

What are those extra index numbers in the beginning of your records?:

```
var storage = [
1:{"index":1, "label": abc, "value": 33},
^
 \---- What's this?
```

Comment: that is an index.
i save my objects in a json array due i use localStorage.

Comment: So it's an object, not an array?  I was confused by the square brackets.

Comment: `find` does not work on Objects.  `find` on lists returns the first matching value, but the notion of "first" on an object is a bit slippery.

Comment: it's the index, because i save my data in localStorage as an array converted to JSON

Comment: I was just trying to understand the structure when it's used in JS.  `[1: {}, 2: {}]` is not legal syntax.  `[{}, {}]` and `{1: {}, 2: {}}` are both fine.